# Attempting to make 3 colums given user inputed data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I will explain this as detailed as I possibly can to prevent any confusion, and I'm sorry in advance for my poor code lingo.

My goal is to take a data set by the user and numbers range from 0 to 100. These numbers will be classified in ranks from A to F in the function **"Rank"**. Then, going by the rank system and input, the scores will be sorted and distributed among the rank to fit within each parameter:`

```
(**A** >= 91, **B** >=81 and score <=90, **C** >=71 and score <=80, 
 **D** >=61 and score <=70, and **F** <=60)
```

This is labeled as **"Count"** For example if there happen to be an 89, 85, and a 61, they would be in the count as 2 B's and 1 D. Finally, there is the **"Percentage"** which then uses the count, and classifies them as a percentage for how many scores are in each rank. So with the previous example the Percentage is 66% for B and 33% for the D rank. I am trying to make my code be executed like this to the user:`

```
>>>GRADE  COUNT   PERCENTAGE
>>>A      0       0%
>>>B      2       66%
>>>C      0       0%
>>>D      1       33%
>>>F      0       0%
```

So far what I have in my code is this:

```
def grade_scores(scoreList):
    count = int(input('Enter amount of scores: ')) 
    print('Each will be entered one per line') 
    scoreList = [] 
    for i in range(1, count+1):   
        scoreList.append(int(input('Enter score: ')))
    for score in range(len(scoreList)): 
        if score >= 91:
            Ascore = 'A'
            count[0] += 1  # Increase index 0 (Corresponds to value A) by 1
            #sum(Ascore) / Acount (scoreList) = Apercentage
        elif score >= 81 and score <=90:
            Bscore = 'B'
            count[1] += 1
            #sum(Bscore) / Bcount (scoreList) = Bpercentage
        elif score >= 71 and score <=80:
            Cscore = 'C'
            count[2] += 1
            #sum(Cscore) / Ccount (scoreList) = Cpercentage
        elif score >= 61 and score <=70:
            Dscore = 'D'
            count[3] += 1
            #sum(Dscore) / Dcount (scoreList) = Dpercentage
        else:
            Fscore = 'F'
            count[4] += 1
            #sum(Dscore) / Dcount (scoreList) = Dpercentage
    print("SCORE  COUNT  PERCENTAGE")
    for i in range(len(grade)):
        print("  {}      {}       {} %".format(grade[i], count[i], percentage[i]))

scores = get_scores()
grade_scores(scores)
```

I know I have quite a bit commented out, I was not able to make the percentage calculation work, and I understand this needs  a lot of work as it is in the drafting stage. I really appreciate any input on this and thank you.

`

Comment: Is your question how to calculate the percentage? If so I don't see anything about that in your code. Additionally please provide a working example.

Comment: @Steven Summers The problem is I don't see why its not working or how I can fix it. When I execute it in the shell, it says "line 123, in grade_scores
    count[4] += 1   NameError: name 'count' is not defined"

Comment: In the example provided you are using `count` to get the initial user input. You are also then using `count` in the if statement block. However this time your are using it as a `list` instead of an `int` which is what it is first defined as. However this is not the error your are getting for some reason. Be careful your are not trying to use local variables from another function.

Comment: @Steven Summers Sorry, this is my first time attempting to write a program as I would like to learn code on my own. My friend provided me with the prompt and once I complete it, he said he would look it over but I'd like to get farther before consulting him.

Comment: It feels like so much is wrong and after days of going at it, I'm not sure what route to take or where to go with it.

Comment: That is fine. When writing programs it is best not to try do everything at once before testing it. I would suggest starting over from scratch and do things in sequence. Get user input, add them to list, iterate through list to determine grade, count grades, find percentage. Do it all step by step and use lots of `prints` as you go to make sure it's working as intended. Because there is a lot happening in your code that is certainly not doing what your think it is.

Comment: Thanks, I will start over and edit my question if I'm still having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This entire post was written with the assumption that this wasn't your first program. The comment about this taking 14 hours was based on my guess that this was an assignment 2 months into programming class. Functions, four? different datatypes, typecasting, list manipulation, output formatting... this is ambitious as heck for a first program. I won't delete this since you might find it interesting, but know that absolutely nothing here is essential.

Based on your other questions, you're been at this for at least 14 hours, so I'll try to show a different way of doing it that will either make more sense or confuse the heck out of you. If it turns out to be the latter, just ignore me and move on. This is just a completely different way of thinking about the problem which may work better for you. It's no better or worse than the way you're going about it.

It's worth mentioning that if this is for programming class, you may not be able to use this. If the teacher/professor is trying to teach you if/elif/else statements, they are not going to be too pleased with code that doesn't use them, regardless of whether it gets the right result.

(EDIT:Just saw your comment that you're teaching yourself programming with this as your first program. Awesome! In that case I highly recommend continuing to master the basics (if, else, for, while, etc.), but this can give you some neat tricks to play around with if nothing else. You should be able to throw most of my examples directly into a program or the python shell if you want to try them out for yourself.)

It's also worth mentioning that I'm (sadly) an attorney. We have no concept of tl/dr. Sorry.

Here is the code:

```
def grade_scores(scoreList):

    grades = 'ABCDF'

    print('Grade, Count, Percentage')

    for i in range(0,5):
        gradeCount = sum([score <+ 100 - 10 * i and (score >= 91 - 10 * i or i == 4) for score in scoreList])

        print(grades[letter], gradeCount, gradeCount/(len(scoreList)-1))
```

The good news is that it's a good deal shorter, it only loops once for each letter grade, and there's way, way less variables to keep track of. Bad news is that you have this behemoth that's wider than the text box:

```
sum([score <= 100 - 10 * i and (score >= 91 - 10 * i or i == 4) for score in scoreList])
```

I know it looks bad, but hang with me. The sum() part is easy. Just like you'd expect, it adds together a list of numbers.

```
s = [1, 2, 3]
sum(s) equals 6
```

Inside the sum() function is special expression called a 'list comprehension', which generally looks like

```
[some expression for i in list]    

#I'm awful with variable consistency, so just assume that no variable carries over
#from example to example.
```

It is just a fancy way of doing something to every element of a list to form a new list.

For example:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
print([x*2 for x in list])
```

will print

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

This is really handy because for each letter grade, we can transform our list of grades into something easy to count. Specifically, we will turn each grade into a 1 or a 0, depending on whether it corresponds to to the letter grade in question.

We can do this by taking advantage of a quirk of programming. True and False are the same as 1 and 0.

For instance:

```
1 > 2 #equals 0,

f = 8
f = f < 10 #will make f equal 1,

#and

list = [1, 2, 1, 2]
print([g == 2 for g in list]) #outputs [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Our goal then is to write an if statement (minus the if) that can work for every letter grade.

You've already written if statements like this:

```
score >= 71 and score <=80
```

and this:

```
score >= 81 and score <=90
```

When you think about it, the only real difference between these statements is 10. A 'B' is less than or equal to 10 * 9, while a 'C' is less than or equal to 10 * 8, all the way down to 'F', 10 * 60.

if you count up from 0 to 4,

```
i * 10 + 60
```

will give you the upper bound of each grade from F to A.

I find it easier to start with A so I just subtract from 100 instead:

```
upper = [100 - i * 10 for i in range(0,5)] 
#range stops before the last number, so range(0,5) = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

[100, 90, 80, 70, 60]
```

The bottom limits works exactly the same way, just starting 9 places lower.

```
lower = [91 - i * 10 for i in range(0,5)]

[91, 81, 71, 61, 51]
```

So if A=0, B=1, etc.,

```
score >= 91 - i * 10 and score <= 100 - i * 10
```

will *almost* give us True or False for every letter grade. The only problem is the pesky 'F.' It doesn't follow the same pattern as all the others, since F's don't stop at 51. We need to write a special case for them.

Based on our pattern F = 4, so if we change the lower bound to

```
(score >= 91 - i * 10 or i == 4)
```

The lower bound will stay set to True the entire time we're looking for F's.

That leaves us with

```
(score >= 91 - i * 10 or i == 4) and score <= 100 - i * 10
```

A statement that will give true or false based on whether score falls into the range of the letter grade i.

From here, we've come full circle back to the behemoth statement:

```
i = 2    #Starting with A equals 0, this makes i equal to C
scoreList = [65, 95, 75, 78]

[(score >= 91 - i * 10 or i == 4) and score <= 100 - i * 10 for score in scoreList]
```

will give us

```
[0, 0, 1, 1]
```

If we add each number in that list with a sum statement, we can know how many C grades are in the list. All we need to do now is make a loop that goes from i = 0 to i = 4,

```
for i in range(0,5):
```

add up our the result of our list comprehension, and print out the results.

This is going to make our print() statement much easier, since now theres not much in the way of variables to deal with. The only real challenges left are printing the letter (since we've only dealt in numbers so far), and getting a percentage.

For the letter, we will just crate a small string containing 'ABCDF'. You can find a letter in a string exactly the same way as you can find an entry in a list.

```
alpha = 'ABCDF'
alpha[3] = 'D'
```

To find the percentage, we now have easy access to the count of each grade, and we can find the total number of grades just by looking at the length of our original list with the len() function. Divide total by count, multiply by 100, and you have a percentage.

```
print(grades[i], gradeCount, (gradeCount/(len(scoreList)*100))
```

each time you go thorough the list gives you everything.

It looks like you've got input well covered, so the only thing left to do is to make the output look pretty, and you seem to have gotten more than enough advice on that. No reason for me to add yet another (probably conflicting) opinion.

Anyway, I hope this helps, or if it doesn't I hope you've had the good sense to ignore me long before this point. Seeing as how this is the stack overflow version of War and Peace, I'm sure that I made a mistake or was unclear somewhere in this mess. I have to meet a programming deadline of my own, but I'll keep an eye out for a quick question or two.